# Is it possible to create computed field in table variables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

My inline table-valued function returns @table and for the time being I'm thinking of a possibility to create field that is to be computed and add formula to it's computed column specification. It might be a better way for me to reduce number of sql statements in my function I think.

So, does it support such feature in functions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
create function foo
(
    @seed int
)
returns @foo_t table
(
    [a] int not null,
    [b] int not null,
    [c] as ([a] + [b])
)
begin
    insert into @foo_t values (@seed, 2)
    insert into @foo_t values (@seed + 1, 3)

    return
end
go

select
    *
from foo(1)
go
```